# I need to loop through 24 columns and use countif for 6 different criteria with values in 6 different cells on another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to loop through 24 columns and use countif for 6 different criteria with values in 6 different cells on another worksheet. This is my biggest worksheet but in total I have 479 columns to go through and 6 different worksheets for my results.

My code is very basic. This checks in 1 column for my values but I have to repeat it and change the range for the result  and change the range for where to look to the next column so I repeat the the code 24 times. I would like to chose the starting cell for the results and just the columns because the rows remain the same for every sheet.

This is my example

```
Toit1.Select
Sheet1.Range("C6") = Toit1.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H8:H69"), "=S")
Sheet1.Range("C7") = Toit1.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H8:H69"), "=E-S")
```

next

```
Sheet1.Range("D6") = Toit1.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("I8:I69"), "=S")
Sheet1.Range("D7") = Toit1.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("I8:I69"), "=E-S")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps iterating through consecutive columns:

```vb
Sub Test()

Dim iChar As Integer, i, j, a
Toit1.Select

a = 72                  'colums searching in; 72 == H
For iChar = 67 To 68    'cells to fill in value (65 ==  A, 66 == B, ...)
    i = Chr(iChar)
        j = Chr(a)
        Sheet1.Range(i & "6") = Toit1.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(i & "8:" & i & "69"), "=S")
        Sheet1.Range(i & "7") = Toit1.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(j & "8:" & j & "69"), "=E-S")
        a = a + 1
Next iChar

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow! it works great and I can adapte for the rest. Thankyou

Comment: Glad to hear that. Maybe you want to accept my answer and give me an upvote ;)